# SSO for multi region architecture

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml

I am the design stage, so open to suggestions (even language or framework are open JAVA/NodeJS/Python Spring/Express/Django etc)

My requirements is to have a multi regional deployment of the system, where each region has its own DB and possibly its own version.
I require a single domain where the user will go to and redirected to the appropriate region, and even then some accounts will use customer's SAML IDP, and some will use our own IDP.

From the user's perspective i thought of something like this:
he will be shown a page where he enters his email (no pw)
with that we will redirect him to the right region,
there if he is a SAML account, he will be redirected to the company's saml login page
if not, we can do simple user/pw login on our IDP

in the background
we can have an auth service with a lookup table in each region, the DB will be replicated across regions
when the user goes to app.acme.com or he will be routed to the auth service in the closest geographical region
the auth service will present him with the first login page where he will enter is email,
auth service will look the email up (by domain) and will redirect to the right auth services (if needed)
there the service will know if he is SAML or not and redirect accordingly

As far as subsequent calls, either the url will change to app-us.acme.com and will be region specific. OR maybe store a session cookie or something lie that that will help direct further calls to the right region.

I am open to different suggestions, and even more open if there is already a framework that has this out of the box

Comment: What's the plan for BC/DR? Should assertions from the IdPs be usable in every region? What demands the regional disparity - A/B testing or Blue/Green deployments? Why shouldn't those be supported within the region as well?

Comment: I dont see how BC/DR is relevant for this question.
The regional disparity is needed since i am going to deal with enterprise companies around the world, each country has its own rules, like GDPR for europe etc, and some countries demand that their data be stored in their own region etc.

I need to be able to support my own IDP, but also support authorizing against my customers' company IDPs in case they have one. The assertions should be per account, and an account is in one specific region.

Comment: PII storage requirements shouldn't drive the architecture beyond being able to retrieve it as required. GDPR demands data at rest sovereignty, not data in transit sovereignty. Instead consider data aggregation tools like a virtual directory or similar that allows you to store your user base regionally, but address it globally. That way your SAML app can be addressed globally, and the application you are frontending can deal with regionalization and i18n as needed.

Comment: first, i wouldnt want to put my DBs on virtual directory, data integrity issues etc.
second PII storage is only part of the reason, there is also the need for separation of versions (EAP, different SLAs, etc).

Comment: Sounds like you have it all planned out. Good luck with your implementation.

Comment: thanks for the comments @AndrewK. These are my current thoughts, i thought to get input from others, maybe there is a more standard way to do this.